# How to make cells automatcially go to a new row

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a table that is 650px wide and I add words to this table...each word is in its own cell.
However if I have too many words then it expands the table.
What I want to do is allow it to limit the X and auto go to a new row or under the current content so it doesn't resize the table.

I thought about calculating the width of each cell using JS..but it says each is 0px as the cells are created programmatically using JS.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a table is not the best solution for you, since it doesn't have this functionality.

You could try simple `<div>`'s, they will wrap, but you could also have a look at the newer, and more advanced, [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). Have a look at the [Wrapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox#wrapping) section on that page.

Comment: So you're saying that this isnt even possible?  with basic DOM object.style....?

Comment: @FU No, I said that a table doesn't have this functionality. Given your answer, you made it possible by getting rid of the table. You're still using table tags, but it's no longer a table. See: [The display CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). It's probably better not to use table tags in this case. It's a simple case of using the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I got it work by using

```
 #tGrammar {
  display: block;
  }

 #tGrammar td {
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

in CSS

and in JS where is tChoicesMain is table

```
tChoicesMain.style.tableLayout = "fixed";
tChoicesMain.style.maxWidth = "650px";
tChoicesMain.setAttribute("id", "tGrammar");
```